# How do i change the display of my class when active

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click a button< it adds a class of active to slide2, I want to change the style of div named slide1 when slide2 is active but why doesn't it work?

EDIT:
codepen : https://codepen.io/jerico001/pen/poeNKBr

here is my javascript

```
<script>
      var next = document.querySelector(".next");
      var previous = document.querySelector(".previous");
      var slide2 = document.querySelector(".slide2");

      next.addEventListener("click", function () {
        slide2.classList.add("active");
      });

      previous.addEventListener("click", function () {
        slide2.classList.remove("active");
      });
    </script>

.slide2.active {
  display: block;
}

.slide2.active .slide1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I think you can implement that function easily in javascript.

Comment: Please edit your question, create a little code snippet (there's a "snippet" button) and put the relevant HTML, JS and CSS in it. So we can see exactly what's going on

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I'd recommend reviewing [ask] for tips on forming your questions that best enables the community to help you.  You'll want to include a [mcve] here, and a clear explanation of the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and what you've tried thus far.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript, by creating a condition as:

```
var specific2=document.getElementsByClassName("slide2");
var specific1=document.getElementsByClassName("slide1");

if(specific2[0].classList.contains("active")){
    specific1[0].style.display="none";
}

/*since getElementsByClassName creates an array with all elements with that classname, you can catch the first element by using [0] if it is your first element with that classname*/
```

Comment: Used this solution and it helped me

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [hidden attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden), along with [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which exposes two handy methods: `toggle()` and `contains()`

```js
const btn    = document.querySelector('#toggle');
const slide1 = document.querySelector('.slide1');
const slide2 = document.querySelector('.slide2');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    slide2.classList.toggle('active');

    slide1.hidden = slide2.classList.contains('active');

});
```

```css
.slides {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

.slide1, .slide2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    float: left;
    border: 3px dotted black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #def;
    margin: 10px;
}

.active {
   background-color: #fed;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>

<div class="slides">

    <div class="slide1">slide one</div>
    <div class="slide2">slide two</div>

</div>
```